# Should "emotion" be singular or plural in "[it] didn't seem to have brought out any emotion/emotions in him"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> Mike got in the car and drove away. The sight of his dad's grave didn't seem to have brought out any emotion/emotions in him.

Is "emotion" a fitting word to use in this context? If so, are both "emotion" and "emotions" okay? Which one is more natural?

Answer (score 1):

to bring out any emotion in him. [uncountable is best here.]

emotions are a series of things: happiness, anger, grief, etc. Ergo, it does not work here.

However, it can be argued that the singular is the same as the uncountable.

Compare:
We didn't have any coffee at tea time.

Same idea: of any + an uncountable noun.